AI Tools for Restructuring an Doctoral Dissertation
I recently changed PhD programs and need to restructure my 325+ page dissertation according to the guidelines of the new program. The subject and approach are the same but the chapter outline/structure to which I am now asked to conform is a bit different.
To be clear, I am doing this with the ok of the new program I have entered as the my dissertation has not previously submitted or published.  Is anyone aware of any AI tools that can help with this.

I would suggest that actual Human Intelligence is required for this. Unless, of course, someone has trained the AI tool using your program's doctoral dissertations exclusively.

Why would you want to run your dissertation through a nonsense-generating machine?

As software questions are excempt, this is not a shopping question.

You've asked for "artificial intelligence" tools and tagged your question with "generative-ai".
I'm not sure that there's really any software tool in that genre which is appropriate for this kind of thing, or at least that's any more efficient than copy, paste, and your own judgement. A few points to consider:

Efficient organization of information and context about a field is part of the likely somewhat novel contribution of your dissertation. While this kind of synthesis isn't as heavily emphasized as your primary-source work, it's still relevant. Diluting your contribution by using tools which produce a kind of guided random walk through previously seen organizational structures seems less than ideal.
The world is now replete with examples of large language models making clear factual errors when prompted to produce technical content. You may find this mitigated somewhat if you're simply prompting to move big chunks of pre-written text around. One of the main components of your academic reputation, however, is trying to minimize such errors in your published writing. You will have to re-read anything that an LLM outputs with a fine-toothed comb to make sure it has not introduced factual errors.
As a technical point, the document you're describing is almost certainly too long to fit whole in the context window for generally available large language models. Here is a discussion of that issue for ChatGPT that pops up on a cursory Google search. Even if it were likely to be useful, I think you'd find it expensive in time, money, and/or computing resources to arrange a solution to this.

In a nutshell: You're already an expert on the content of your document and presumably not an expert on resolving technical issues at the limits of what LLM's can output. It seems likely to me that you'd find it much more efficient to do the reorganization yourself.

Your dissertation is meant to be the proof that you are qualified to be an independent researcher. It should be the thing that you are the world expert in, the documents that you are the only person in the world who is qualified to write.
If it's something that an AI can write, then it's not something that's worthy of a dissertation.
If you edit the AI output enough that it's considered your writing, is it really less work than just editing the original document? AI written text is the worst to proofread: it sounds plausible but contains factual errors. The plausibility of the writing makes the errors that much harder to find.
See, for example, Stochastic Parrots and ChatGPT is Bullshit.
